# customizing order gridlayoutmanager - horizontal

Tags: java, android

```
GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),2, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager); // set LayoutManager to RecyclerView
```

this code output like

```
1 3 5 7
2 4 6 8
```

but I want the output like this

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
```

how to ordering like that?

Comment: Try this (change orientation) 
GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 4, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false)

Answer (score 1):

Your `GridLayoutManager` orientation should be `vertical` to make that happen. You also need to consider using 4 columns instead of 2, so use:

```
GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 4)
```

The default orientation is `vertical`.